# Error run in IOS

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image]I m working on Xamarin Forms project using Visual Studio 2017 in windows PC,I want  to run my application in IOS emulator . I Checked with android and its working fine , I have a mac mini and  I connected it using Visual Studio agent .when i run the application using Visual Studio agent i m getting this error .

Extra linker definitions file '/Users/macmini3/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MN.IOSApp/2fdeec2fb7f48e99f4fd7886d5cce712/LinkDescription.xml' could not be located. MN.IOSApp

I have attached my ios build configuration

Comment: can you share screenshot of iOS project>properties>iOS Build

Comment: @HoussemDbira Dbira  i have uploaded with screen shot

Comment: Houssem Dbira when i remove 3 ticks and  --xml=${ProjectDir}/LinkDescription.xml application runs but give errors

Comment: Just remove the `--xml=${ProjectDir}/LinkDescription.xml`, close your project, delete the bin and obj folder, open and clean your project. Then deploy to see whether it will give some errors.